# Select item class which has been assigned on submit in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am trying to select a class which has been assigned on jQuery submit. I am unable to select the class.

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
  $.ajax({
  success: function(data) {
  $("#" + key).addClass("missed");
});

$('input.missed').click(function() {
    alert("Clicked");
});
```

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Missing closing brackets on `success` callback

Comment: ...and missing `});` on ajax call

Comment: And you do not cancel the submit action.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

In assuming that question is "How do I add a click handler to elements after a submit event?" then the answer could be that your success call back has several syntax errors and your indentation suggests that you are managing the DOM in the incorrect order. To illustrate here is some annotated code:

```
$('form.ajax').on('submit', function(e) {
  // Prevent an actual submission in favor of AJAX
  e.preventDefault();
  // Spawn an AJAX request to http://ecample.com/api/form_validator
  $.ajax({url: 'http://example.com/api/form_validator'})
    // Once we have a success response *then* do the following.
    .then(function(response) {
      // Use the response from the server to iterate of the keys array.
      $.each(response.keys, function(i, key) {
        // add the missing class to the element that matches the key.
        $('#element-' + key).addClass('missed');
      });
    });
});

// Assign a click event to the entire form but filter it by 'input.missing'
// this way whe an input does have the missingf class the click will happen
// otherwise it is ignored. This is call event delegation.
$('form.ajax').on('click', 'input.missed', function(e) {
  alert('Clicked');
});
```

This is call [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: I have create the code for example purposes, just to show what I am trying to achieve after the sucessful or unsucessful submitino. The problem I face is that added class via first instance of the code could not be found by the instance of second.

Comment: Seems you haven't read the answer above. There is no second instance you speak of. The code you provided does not have such. And even if it did the execution would still be out of order!. Either use event delegation of jQuery's `live()` method.

Comment: Is there an easier way doint it? 
$("form.ajax").on("keyup", "input[data-invalid='true']", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("missed");
});

$("form.ajax").on("focusout", "input[data-invalid='true']", function(e) {   
    if ($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).addClass("missed");
    }
});

$("form.ajax").on("focusin", "input[data-invalid='true']", function(e) {
    $(this).removeClass("missed");
});

Comment: I have no idea what that was. Make a jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net those sites are easier to diagnose/debug. Both support AJAX options.